# Fan 0 RPM, hardware or software error?

Tags: kubuntu, lenovo, thinkpad, fan, overheating

I have a new computer and after approx. two weeks I noticed the unit heating up and the fan no longer on.  I have checked and despite the heat, it is always at 0 RPM. I was unable to find any fan options in the BIOS.

Is there an easy way to check if this is a hardware or software fault?

Many thanks!

My system:
Kubuntu 21.04
Lenovo Thinkpad L13 Yoga 2nd Gen

### Update 1 (2021-06-16)

@Terrance Thanks for the tip with the Live USB!

I ran the live USB without installing Kubuntu and the laptop was quite hot and I heard no fan. I then installed lm-sensors (still on the live USB) via

```
sudo apt install lm-sensors
```

and checked the fan speed with:

```
sensors | grep -i fan
```

I still get

```
fan1: 0 RPM
```

Can I then assume that I have a hardware fault?

Comment: If you boot to a Live USB that will eliminate your installed OS as being the issue.  The fan should be running all the time the system is turned on.

Answer (score 1):

It was indeed a faulty fan, which has been now replaced.

Strangely

```
sensors | grep -i fan
```

is still showing

```
fan1: 0 RPM
```

But fan is running and temperatures much lower.

Comment: How did you determine the issue was in hardware?